# Declaration of RabbitMQQueue::createPayloadArray($job, $queue, $data = '') should be compatible with Queue::createPayloadArray($job, $data = '')

Tags: php, laravel, rabbitmq, queue

So here is my situation. I am on `Laravel 5.7`. For queues I am using [this](https://github.com/vyuldashev/laravel-queue-rabbitmq/tree/v8.3.0) package with version `8.3.0`.

Now when I try to start the queue worker it renders the following error:

> Declaration of
> VladimirYuldashev\LaravelQueueRabbitMQ\Queue\RabbitMQQueue::createPayloadArray($job,
> $queue, $data = '') should be compatible with
> Illuminate\Queue\Queue::createPayloadArray($job, $data = '')
> {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Declaration of
> VladimirYuldashev\LaravelQueueRabbitMQ\Queue\RabbitMQQueue::createPayloadArray($job,
> $queue, $data = '') should be compatible with
> Illuminate\Queue\Queue::createPayloadArray($job, $data = '') at
> /home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/vendor/vladimir-yuldashev/laravel-queue-rabbitmq/src/Queue/RabbitMQQueue.php:17)

Here is the stack trace:

```
[2021-01-05 08:59:26] local.ERROR: Declaration of VladimirYuldashev\LaravelQueueRabbitMQ\Queue\RabbitMQQueue::createPayloadArray($job, $queue, $data = '') should be compatible with Illuminate\Queue\Queue::createPayloadArray($job, $data = '') {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Declaration of VladimirYuldashev\\LaravelQueueRabbitMQ\\Queue\\RabbitMQQueue::createPayloadArray($job, $queue, $data = '') should be compatible with Illuminate\\Queue\\Queue::createPayloadArray($job, $data = '') at /home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/vendor/vladimir-yuldashev/laravel-queue-rabbitmq/src/Queue/RabbitMQQueue.php:17)
[stacktrace]
#0 /home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/vendor/vladimir-yuldashev/laravel-queue-rabbitmq/src/Queue/RabbitMQQueue.php(17): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\HandleExceptions->handleError(2, 'Declaration of ...', '/home/vagrant/c...', 17, Array)
#1 /home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(444): include('/home/vagrant/c...')
#2 /home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(322): Composer\\Autoload\\includeFile('/home/vagrant/c...')
#3 [internal function]: Composer\\Autoload\\ClassLoader->loadClass('VladimirYuldash...')
#4 /home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/app/Domain/Configuration/MultiTenantQueue/Queue.php(19): spl_autoload_call('VladimirYuldash...')
#5 /home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(444): include('/home/vagrant/c...')
#6 /home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(322): Composer\\Autoload\\includeFile('/home/vagrant/c...')
#7 [internal function]: Composer\\Autoload\\ClassLoader->loadClass('Phirater\\\\Domain...')
#8 /home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/app/Domain/Configuration/MultiTenantQueue/Connector.php(36): spl_autoload_call('Phirater\\\\Domain...')
#9 /home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/QueueManager.php(157): Phirater\\Domain\\Configuration\\MultiTenantQueue\\Connector->connect(Array)
#10 /home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/QueueManager.php(138): Illuminate\\Queue\\QueueManager->resolve('worker')
#11 /home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(107): Illuminate\\Queue\\QueueManager->connection('worker')
#12 /home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Console/WorkCommand.php(101): Illuminate\\Queue\\Worker->daemon('worker', 'dev', Object(Illuminate\\Queue\\WorkerOptions))
#13 /home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Console/WorkCommand.php(85): Illuminate\\Queue\\Console\\WorkCommand->runWorker('worker', 'dev')
#14 [internal function]: Illuminate\\Queue\\Console\\WorkCommand->handle()
#15 /home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(29): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#16 /home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(87): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::Illuminate\\Container\\{closure}()
#17 /home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(31): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
#18 /home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(564): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
#19 /home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(183): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->call(Array)
#20 /home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(255): Illuminate\\Console\\Command->execute(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\\Console\\OutputStyle))
#21 /home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(170): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Command\\Command->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\\Console\\OutputStyle))
#22 /home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(1009): Illuminate\\Console\\Command->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#23 /home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(273): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Illuminate\\Queue\\Console\\WorkCommand), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#24 /home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(149): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#25 /home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php(89): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#26 /home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(122): Illuminate\\Console\\Application->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#27 /home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/artisan(35): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#28 {main}
"}
```

My configuration of the package is exactly as mentioned in the `github` docs. I am on `Laravel 5.`7 with `PHP 7.3`. What is the solution to this problem? Any help?

Comment: VladimirYuldashev\LaravelQueueRabbitMQ\Queue\RabbitMQQueue::createPayloadArray() has different arguments than Illuminate\Queue\Queue::createPayloadArray().

Comment: @TrầnQuangSơn yes I know that, but the question is why is that? As the package successfully installed with the current of itself and Laravel 5.7 then why it is not compatible?

Comment: I am not very familiar with Laravel 5.7 but you can follow this url and check.
https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Queue/Queue.html and https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Queue/Queue.html
You can search createPayloadArray() and see there is a arguments different between 2 versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this package has very intricate versions relations to laravel releases (and 5.7 are not supported now).

According to this commit - https://github.com/vyuldashev/laravel-queue-rabbitmq/commit/3ee048910abb54b7fd730ea328ddb1db8161a563 - you can try either 11 or 7 (see https://github.com/vyuldashev/laravel-queue-rabbitmq/issues/229)

Comment: I used the version 7.3 and the issue was gone for me.